# Vuex, computed properties are not reactive

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I trying to have a state shared between some components (sub-components) that where each sub-combonent (and parent component) can update the shared property (store in vueX state).

I have make a small "How to reproduce" here:

```
Vue.component('urlQueryComponent', {
  template: '<div>object: {{pathQuery}}</div>',
  computed: {
    pathQuery () {
      return this.$store.state.urlQuery;
    }
  }
})
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvmLrZ?editors=1010

The problem it's when I update state in sub component, the changes are not handled.

The VueX instance:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    urlQuery:  {
      path: '',
      query: {}
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    pushQuery: (state, type) => {
      state.urlQuery.query[type.key] = type.value;
      console.log('urlQuery: ', state.urlQuery);
    },
    pushPath: (state, path) => {
      state.urlQuery.path = path;
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getUrlQuery: state => state.urlQuery
  }
})
```

And the parent component:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  methods: {
    changeType (type) {
      this.$store.commit('changeType', type);
    }
  }
})
```

**EDIT:**

After reflection, The code before are not realy targeted to my problem. [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ctvgdd0c/2/) are more targeted to my problem.

Comment: it seems you created new properties. so uses [Vue API: set](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set); like `this.$set(state.urlQuery.query, type.key, type.value)`

Comment: You can use with `this.$set()` or `Ojbect.assign()`

Comment: @AdrianoResende, yes. I have solve my problem with `Vue.set()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `pushQuery` mutation to:

```
pushQuery: ({ urlQuery }, type) => {
  const key = type.key
  Vue.set(urlQuery.query, key, type.value)
  console.log('urlQuery: ', urlQuery);
}
```

it should work ([fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/StpFlp_DDK/3ne9ch7v/))

**Source** ([Vuex mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html)) :

> Mutations Follow Vue's Reactivity Rules
>   Since a Vuex store's state is made reactive by Vue, when we mutate the state, Vue components observing the state will update automatically. This also means Vuex mutations are subject to the same reactivity caveats when working with plain Vue:
>
> 1. Prefer initializing your store's initial state with all desired fields upfront.
> 2. When adding new properties to an Object, you should either use :    `Vue.set(obj, 'newProp', 123)`